How Do I Ask a Contractor to Fix Carpet Seam (technically speaking)?
I have a contractor working on installing carpet. They're coming back today to do the stairs. I want them to blend this seam better. I'm prepared to be told it can't be done. Granted, all I know is the seam in the same place wasn't visible in the old carpet.
To be fair, it could be worse. To be fair to myself, we hired a pro to do it right.
What should I ask of the contractor that is possible? I don't know enough about techniques or tools in case I need more than "please blend this more". One of the sections of carpet is relatively small, so I wouldn't feel bad if it requires redoing that. About 6 feet of hallway.


I would try rubbing a hand across the seam a few times first.

@crip659 we tried that and vacuumed. Sadly, no dice

Carpet pile lays in a certain direction - it's a characteristic of how the carpet is manufactured. Some recommend that the carpet should be oriented so that the pile direction is toward the opening of a room so that one sees the true color of the carpet as they enter. Others recommend that on stairs the pile should be directed so it runs up the stairs.
In any case, if we assume that both sides of the seam come from the same roll or at least the same dye lot, perhaps the reason for the visible seam is that the pile is oriented different directions on each side of the seam.
I'm no carpet expert so take my explanation with a grain of salt -- but you could inspect the carpet yourself to check the pile direction, or ask some directed questions of your installer to probe whether pile direction might be a factor here.
If a mismatch of pile direction is indeed the cause then the fix is to replace the carpet on one side to match the direction of the other side. This might create some waste and you may be asked to pay for more material.
